# NSError strange issue - app crashes while trying to access NSError's properties

Tags: iphone, ios, nserror

In the following code `NSError` instantiates (match is GameCenter's GKMatch):

```
    ...
    NSString * deviceID = appDelegate.deviceID;
    MessageWithDeviceID message;
    message.message.messageType = kMessageTypeDeviceID;
    const char* const deviceIDAsUTF8 = deviceID.UTF8String;
    for (size_t idx=0;idx<32;idx++)
        message.deviceID[idx] = deviceIDAsUTF8[idx];

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&message length:sizeof(message)];
    NSError * error;
    [match sendDataToAllPlayers:data withDataMode:GKMatchSendDataReliable error:&error];

    data  = nil;
    if (error) 
    NSLog(@"An error is occured: %@",error);
    ...
```

but the app crashes at the last shown line with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` or `SIGABRT -[NSCFString userInfo (or domain, localizedDescription, code etc)] unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x...`. So I can see that error is not nil and it is instantiated object but I can't get any information from it. I tried to get the following:

```
[error localizedDescription];
[error domain];
[error code];
[error description];
etc.
```

but app still crashes at `NSLog` line no matter which info I'm trying to get. I know the approach isn't right and I need to use `BOOL` variable in line which sends data but thats not the point of question. The question is whats wrong with the `NSError` object? I could see error's fields in debugger (those expandable info) like:

```
NSObject       NSObject
void *         _reserved
NSInteger      _code        875902004  Summary
NSString *     _domain
NSDictionary * _userInfo
```

So it seems like error object does have all the info but its unaccessible... Why is it so? Is `NSError` somehow not fully/completely instantiated or something?

Comment: try `NSError* error = nil;`

Comment: As you said yourself: Your approach isn't right. You should check the *return value* of the method. If it returns `NO`, the error variable will contain a valid object describing the problem.

Comment: But this doesn't explain the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try initializing your error pointer to nil

```
NSError * error = nil;
```

You get a crash because there was no error and your pointer contains a random address.

Comment: faster but time is same do't know who is first ? :) +1

Comment: Your comment below the question was faster than my answer :)

Comment: hm i put the comment but no response that's i add answer too but there is you too. good luck

Comment: But this doesn't help (EXC_BAD_ACCESS is fixed however). I'm still getting -[NSCFString userInfo (or domain, localizedDescription, code etc)] unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x... like error is not an NSError instance.

Comment: It looks like your pointer is pointing to an instance of NSString. Are manipulating the error pointer in any other way?

Comment: Perhaps you should debug your code and see when the error pointer changes from nil to a different value.

Comment: there is actually nothing to debug cuz error pointer changes in one and only line: [match sendDataToAllPlayers:data withDataMode:GKMatchSendDataReliable error:&error].

Answer (score 3):

Replace this line.

```
NSError* error = nil;
```

Comment: But this doesn't help (EXC_BAD_ACCESS is fixed however). I'm still getting -[NSCFString userInfo (or domain, localizedDescription, code etc)] unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x...